# Protected member is "not declared in this scope" in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base
{
protected:
    std::vector<T> data_;
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
    void clear()
    {
        data_.clear();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived<int> derived;
    derived.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot compile this program. I get:

```
main.cpp:22: error: 'data_' was not declared in this scope
```

Please, could you explain why `data_` is not visible in the `Derived` class?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To fix this, you need to specify `Base<T>::data_.clear()` or `this->data_.clear()`. As for why this happens, see [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members).

Comment: Thank you! It works in both cases with Base<T>::data_.clear() or this->data_.clear()!

Comment: `Derived::data_.clear()` also works.

Comment: For me this is a bug in compiler. It should look into bases class(es). Who cares if names is dependent o not.

Comment: @KirillKobelev, I would say not having `this->` is compiler limitation rather than a bug. Imagine a case where the base class is specialized for `int`, i.e. `Base<int>` and that class doesn't have `data_`. Now compiler doesn't know whether current `Derived<T>` is specialized for `int` or not. If compiler assumes `this->` then it will become a real bug.

Comment: @KirillKobelev: MSVC compiler will accept `data_.clear();`, but that is because it doesn't implement two-phase name lookup.

Comment: @iammilind, you would be right in a general case, if we do not have a complete example. But here, there are no specializations, error message is generated at the point of instantiation where specializations if any are already resolved. `this->` looks like something for dummies.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of templates compiler is not able to determine if the member is really coming from base class. So use `this` pointer and it should work:

```
void clear()
{
   this->data_.clear();
}
```

When compiler looks the Derived class definition, it doesn't know which `Base<T>` is being inherited (as `T` is unknown). Also `data_` is not any of the `template` parameter or globally visible variable. Thus compiler complains about it.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion works!